# Caching caused DOMContentLoaded event not fired

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, litespeed, domcontentloaded

Playing with LiteSpeed Cache (LSC) plugin for WordPress and found it caused one plugin (Revolution Slider) not working.

```
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: setREVStartSize is not defined
```

The slider plugin's function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">setREVStartSize({
```

is rewritten by the cache plugin to

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { setREVStartSize({
```

But this event was not fired.

Here is a comparison of function setREVStartSize after/before LSC is enabled

https://editor.mergely.com/yp8ZF9dP/ (Please click Options -> Wrap Lines and Ignore White Space)

- Left : when LSC is enabled
- Right: when LSC is disabled

The only difference is how and when the function is fired.

Here is a comparison of how the slider calls the function:

https://editor.mergely.com/vuoEakJB/
(Please click Options -> Wrap Lines and Ignore White Space)

- Left : when LSC is enabled
- Right: when LSC is disabled

This seems to be a bug. I am not sure if the plugin developer will or when will fix the bug. Anything that I can do on my own to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: what if you disable JS combine , JS minify and defer JS ?